# Turn Div Background-Image into link

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, background

I have a div with a background image:

[image]

You will notice that it is just a small arrow. 
I am using the background-image because it is easy to center images with it.

Now the Arrow needs to be a link. My Problem is, that the div has 100% width to center the background-image properly: So when I use `<a>` the full div can be clicked anywhere and it is working as a link.
Do I have any possibility to make only the arrow clickable as a link using background-image?

My HTML:

```
<div class="row3">

    <div class="ArrowToTop" style="background-image:url(../img/basics/ArrowToTop.png);background-size: contain; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center;">
    <a href="#firstPage" style="display:block; width:100%; height:100%;"></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row3 .ArrowToTop{
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you add `background-image` to `a` tag, or just add `img` to `a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your life easier and don't use inline styles.

`a` should be `inline-block` or `inline` and the parent should have `text-align:center`.